# How can we move current filter (Not whole layered navigation)?

Tags: magento2

How can we move current filter (Not whole layered navigation)?

[image]

Comment: `Not whole layered navigation`?

Comment: Any solutions to move the current filter only?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about the "State" of the layered navigation.
The layered navigation itself is the "FilterRenderer".

You'll find it in these 2 files:

- vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml
- vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml

You can add layout updates in your custom layout XML to remove the block and add it elsewhere.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter"/>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

```
<block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to remove state section from filter then 
you have to move this block by below code

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.navigation.state" remove="true">
```

That you have to create `catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml` & `catalogsearch_result_index.xml` at **app/design/frontend/{ThemeVendor}/{Themename}/Magento_LayeredNavigation/layout** and add below code both two files.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <referenceBlock name="catalog.navigation.state" remove="true">
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

In my theme copy of: `catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml`

I copy the sidebar filters and use different names for them (you need them all for the filters to render), then I hide what I don't need with css

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.custom.topnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state.top" as="state" />
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer.top" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: It works, But i am using amasty filter and layered navigation work through ajax. So, Once i select any attribute the product result get update but the filter reflect only if i reload the page. Not working with the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the status in other phtml file when use this block
@var $block \Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Block\Navigation
example in this page

```
vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog/view/frontend/templates/layer/view.phtml
```

exist this block, you can use this call

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('state') ?>
```

I hope help you,regards